# `go install` not working on Mac

Tags: macos, go, command-line

I wanted to install a Go binary with `go install`. So I have downloaded the sources with

```
go get -v github.com/spf13/cobra/cobra
```

which gave me

```
 $GOPATH/src
     └── github.com
         └── spf13
             ├── cobra
             └── pflag
```

I created a `$GOPATH/bin` directory. When I now run

```
go install github.com/spf13/cobra/cobra
```

(as stated in the documentation), nothing happens - there is no error message but after the command run, there is also no binary in `$GOPATH/bin`.

Here is the output of my `go env`

```
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN="/Users/user/Workspace/go/bin"
GOEXE=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="darwin"
GOOS="darwin"
GOPATH="/Users/user/Workspace/go"
GORACE=""
GOROOT="/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6/libexec"
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6/libexec/pkg/tool/darwin_amd64"
GO15VENDOREXPERIMENT="1"
CC="clang"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -fno-caret-diagnostics -Qunused-arguments -fmessage-length=0 -fno-common"
CXX="clang++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
```

Any idea what's going wrong or how I can probably debug this? Thanks!

**Edit**

What solved the problem for me was to delete the `$GOPATH/src` and `$GOPATH/pkg`folder and re-run `go get -v -x github.com/spf13/cobra/cobra`.

The `-x`flag provides more output and as stated by @JimB it ended successfully with

```
mv $WORK/github.com/spf13/cobra/cobra/_obj/exe/a.out /Users/user/Workspace/go/bin/cobra
```

Comment: `go get` also runs `install`, so `go install` shouldn't output anything. However you should have a binary in `$GOPATH/bin/`. Can you reinstall and use the `-x` flag to see what exactly is happening? The last command run should be to `mv` the `a.out` to `$GOPATH/bin/cobra`

Comment: thanks - re-installing did the trick! When I first ran `go get...` there was only 1 additional package downloaded - this time it's been many more...

Comment: You may have already had an old checkout of cobra in your GOPATH. You can use `go get -u` as a quick way to pull a fresh checkout from master.